# Exporting blender shape keys animation to Unity

Tags: animation, export, unity, shape-keys, vertex-groups

I created simple object with some vertex groups and shape keys and added keyframes based on the shape keys. I have problem with exporting this animation to unity. It just shows that there is only one frame in the animations section of this prefab. Do you have any idea what may be source of this problem. I'm new to blender and unity so I might have done some stupid mistakes. I watched many tutorials about exporting, but all of them were about exporting animation with bones.

Comment: I always just exported the whole object as an fbx file. That has never let me down. If you do this and it doesn't work, It's not something I'm familliar with.

Comment: Have you applied all modifiers and applied location, rotation and scale? Second thing that comes into my mind, try to export the fbx file instead of let Unity import the blend file.

Comment: Perhaps this video will shed some light on the issue:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wvjwTnS6vhA